# R: Reduce axis to geom_density_ridges distance after flipping plot with coord_flip in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

First we prepare some toy data that sufficiently resembles the one I am working with.

```
rawdata <- data.frame(Score = rnorm(1000, seq(1, 0, length.out = 10), sd = 1),
                      Group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10000))
stdev <- c(10.78,10.51,9.42)
```

Now we plot the estimated densities via `geom_density_ridges`. I also add a grey highlight around zero via `geom_rect`. I also flip the chart with `coord_flip`.

```
p <- ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = Score, y = Group)) +
     scale_y_discrete() +
     geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), 
               fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
     geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = Group), scale = 0.5, size = 1, alpha=0.5) +
     scale_color_manual(values = col) +   
     scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
     labs(title="Toy Graph", y="Group", x="Value") +
     coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE, clip = "on")

p
```

[image]
And this is the solution I get, which is close to what I was expecting, despite the detail of this enormous gap between the y axis an the start of the first factor in the x axis `A`. I tried using `expand=c(0,0)` inside `scale_y_discrete()` following some suggestions from other posts, but it does not make the gap smaller at all. If possible I would still like to have a certain gap, although minimal. I've been also trying to flip the densities in the y axis so the gap is filled by first factor density plot but I have been unsuccessful as it does not seem as trivial as one could expect.

Sorry, I know this might be technically two different questions, "How to reduce the gap from the y axis to the first density plot?" and "How to flip the densities from y axis to reduce the gap?" But I would really be happy with the first one as I understand the second question seems to be apparently less straightforward.

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Btw, just for reproducibility and to be exact, I forgot to add the colours vector I was using in my post ```col <- c("#004d8d", "#cc2701", "#e5b400")```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flipping the densities also effectively reduces the space, so this might be all you need to do. You can achieve it with a negative `scale` parameter:

```r
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = Score, y = Group)) +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            mapping = aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, 
                          xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), 
                          xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), 
            fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = Group), scale = -0.5, size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +   
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  labs(title = "Toy Graph", y = "Group", x = "Value") +
  coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE, clip = "on")
```

[image]

If you want to keep the densities pointing the same way but just reduce space on the left side, simply set hard limits in your `coord_flip`, with no expansion:

```r
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = Score, y = Group)) +
  geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            mapping = aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, 
                          xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), 
                          xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), 
            fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = Group), scale = 0.5, size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +   
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  labs(title = "Toy Graph", y = "Group", x = "Value") +
  coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = c(0.8, 4), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, I didn't find the option anywhere. Thanks very much for your help!